# LWP::Curl installation trying to connect to internet

Tags: perl, curl

My team is trying to install the `LWP::Curl` module on
an AIX server and is facing an issue.

We are using Perl v5.8.8 and are trying to install `LWP::Curl` v0.14.
We have successfully installed **Curl v7.40** on our AIX server.

During installation of `LWP::Curl` it seems that the `Curl.pm` package is trying to connect to internet and is unable to do so. Our AIX server is not connected to internet.

- Is this connection necessary?
- Can we bypass this connection and still install the module?

I have posted excerpts from the log

```
*** Your host cannot resolve the domain name 'cpan.org', which  
    probably means the Internet connections are unavailable.
==> Should we try to install the required module(s) anyway? [n] y
```

if we  select ‘Y’  search the dependencies on internet ('cpan.org' )

```
*** Installing Test::Exception...
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /home/root/.cpan/Metadata
Warning: Found only 0 objects in /home/root/.cpan/Metadata
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok
Fetching with LWP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[LWP::Protocol::MyFTP: Bad hostname 'ftp.perl.org']
Fetching with Net::FTP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Issuing "/usr/bin/ftp -n"
ftp : Unknown host ftp.perl.org
Not connected.
Local directory now /home/root/.cpan/sources/authors
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.
Bad luck... Still failed!
Can't access URL ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.
```

Answer (score 2):

> Our AIX server is not connected to internet.

I would have thought it was obvious that `cpan` cannot work without a connection to the internet. Surely you don't think all the sources of all the CPAN modules are stored on your system?

But if you want to install random Perl modules on an isolated system then you will have to do exactly that. I suggest you take a look at [`CPAN::Mini`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Mini). If you install it on a machine that *is* connected to the internet and use it to build a mirroe then you can copy the mirror over to your offline system and use that to install modules

An alternative would be to download the .tar.gz package files of the modules manually (for instance from [`LWP-Curl-0.14`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Elorn/LWP-Curl-0.14/)) copy them over to your AIX system and install from there using the process described in [`perlmodinstall`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html)

But note that doing things this way removes much of the convenience of `cpan`, in particular you must establish any missing dependencies (perhaps using the [*CPAN Dependencies*](http://deps.cpantesters.org/) site) and download and install those in the same way. You will also have to be much more careful about keeping modules up to date, as all of that must be done manually too

Comment: "Surely you don't think all the sources of all the CPAN modules are stored on your system?" — [All 22Gb of them](http://www.cpan.org/misc/how-to-mirror.html)

Comment: And, of course, there is [CPAN::Mini](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Mini). But, seriously, this question has the flavor of "I unplugged the computer, why won't it turn on?"